# JavaScript: How to explain and understand functions with parameters that seem to have no value?

Tags: javascript, parameters, nested

starting to learn JavaScript and reading the book "Eloquent JavaScript" for starters. I'm having a little difficulty understanding the `factor` parameter in the `hummus function`. Can someone help me understand what the starting value of `factor`is? I can see the values for the `ingredient function`but can't seem to wrap my head around the value of `factor`. Would appreciate the help!

```
 const hummus = function(factor) {
  const ingredient = function(amount, unit, name) {
    let ingredientAmount = amount * factor;
    if (ingredientAmount > 1) {
      unit += "s";
    }
    console.log(`${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}`);
  };
  ingredient(1, "can", "chickpeas");
  ingredient(0.25, "cup", "tahini");
  ingredient(0.25, "cup", "lemon juice");
  ingredient(1, "clove", "garlic");
  ingredient(2, "tablespoon", "olive oil");
  ingredient(0.5, "teaspoon", "cumin");
};
```

Comment: Without seeing where `hummus` is called, it's impossible to say

Comment: hummus is a function.  It takes parameter "factor".  In contrast to other languages like C, C++ or Java: `In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are Function objects.`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions  Q: Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code sample, a function is assigned to a const `ingredient`

```
const ingredient = function(amount, unit, name) {
    let ingredientAmount = amount * factor;
    if (ingredientAmount > 1) {
      unit += "s";
    }
    console.log(`${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}`);
  };
```

Once you have a function you can call it, which is `ingredient(1, "can", "chickpeas");`

Similarly you need to make a call to `hummus`, maybe something like `hummus(0.3)` or `hummus(1)` passing it a value.

Your code doesn't contain the call to `hummus` and the value of factor will be set based on the value that you pass to it when making a call.

If `hummus` is called like `hummus()` without a value, in that case factor will be set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the factor isn't shown here, but any value you input represents the amount of hummus you plan to make. For example `hummus(2)` would be two batches of hummus.

The inner function `ingredient` will then establish the amount of each ingredient needed based on the number of batches, and if the ingredient amount (based on amount multiplied by the number of batches) is more than 1 it will add an "s" to the string to make it plural.

What confused me a lot about this example in the book was the introduction of string interpolation here: console.log(`${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}`). This is not discussed in the book before being introduced here. The back ticks, rather than single or double quotes, are important for the code to recognise the string interpolation.

The example of the output for the `hummus` function on [this page](https://www.mattjennings.net/javascript-functions) helped me to understand it better.

As did [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO4TNhNNeYs) on string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `factor` isn't shown in your example.  Somewhere needs to invoke like `var x = hummus(2);` or somesuch so you'll know what's being passed in for factor in that instance.